# Add string to select query based on content of another field in Microsoft Access

Tags: microsoft-access

I am currently trying to generate a select query that appends a specific string to the front of the field if another field has a different, specific string as well. If the other field does not have that string, I want the record returned as is.

So, if `[Table].[Col2] = X` then append "Y" to the beginning of string in `[Table].[Col1]`, but if false, report and continue.

This seems somewhat trivial but I do not see a straight-forward result for this. Is this possible?

**EDIT:**
In addition to this general idea, I need to convert Col1 data type to a string as part of the query since it is currently stored as a Double.  I have created an Append Query pointed to a table with a text data type for that field, but still the query provided in comments does not add the string to the output.  It only reports the value of the field.  Whats even more complicated is the string Y is a special character; that said, I have experimented with suggested syntax using normal characters and still not working.  I am beginning to think it is not possible, but any help or suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean `if([Table].[Col2]="X","Y","") & [Table].[Col1]`?

Comment: OK, after a bit of back and forth, this does in fact output all results, but it does not add the Y to the front of Col1, it just reports Col1.  Do I need to make a new column and name it for the modified output?

Comment: OK, I know the problem, I am telling with my argument to add a string to a NUMERIC FIELD!  Is there a way that as part of this argument I can actually change the numeric field to a string?

Comment: "as part of this argument I can actually change the numeric field to a string? " - I don't understand your problem. When you query a table, original data types are not inherited, they change automatically to fit the information. Please share more details how and where you'll need to use the data.